# Split array into arrays of matching values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of values similar to:

```
["100", "330", "22", "100", "4.7", "0.01", "0.01", "330", "0.01", "100", "47", "22", "100", "0.01"]
```

Using JavaScript I would like to split this array into a number of arrays where only matching strings are in those arrays like this:

```
["100", "100", "100"]
["330", "330"]
["22", "22"]
["0.01", "0.01", "0.01", "0.01"]
["47"]
["4.7"]
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything as of yet, I'm still relatively new to JavaScript and don't know where to start

Comment: This part seems not valid: `"0.01, "330", 0.01"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could collect with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and get the values as result.

From inside out:

- Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with `data` and use a `Map` instance as *`initialValue`*.
- As callback take [`Map#set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) and collect the values for each group.

Further methods:

- [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for getting all items of an iterable together with
- [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) for having a default value for spreading.
- Get the values from the map and use it as parameter for
- [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). This generates an array of all values.

```js
var data = ["100", "330", "22", "100", "4.7", "0.01", "0.01", "330", "0.01", "100", "47", "22", "100", "0.01"],
    result = Array.from(data
        .reduce((m, v) => m.set(v, [...m.get(v) || [], v]), new Map)
        .values()
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this solution! Could you also add a few comments for me to help me understand and learn the code I'm using :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `reduce` method and `Object.values`

```
   //Go thru each value in `arr` array and convert into object with 
   //keys as unique (value in array) and values array of value repetitions.


   {
     "100": ["100", "100"],
     "22": ["22"],
     ...
     ...    
   }

   //Use the Object.values to get the Values as array of arrays
```

```js
const arr = ["100", "330", "22", "100", "4.7", "0.01", "0.01", 
             "330", "0.01", "100", "47", "22", "100","0.01"];

const updated = Object.values(
  arr.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => (
      (acc[curr] = curr in acc ? [...acc[curr], curr] : [curr]), acc
    ),
    {}
  )
);

console.log(updated);
```

Comment: Spreading out the accumulator is a bad practice. Consider returning the accumulator instead.

Comment: @Siva could you just explain the code to me so I can get a better understanding of it? I like to understand the code I'm using!

Comment: Sure @Alex i will add details soon.

Comment: @AlexMorrison, updated the answer with comments. Hope that helps.

Comment: @SivaKondapiVenkata You have made it a lot more complicated than it has to be

Comment: Got it @Kobe, Again updated bring back to initial version with return statement and comments as Alex asked. Thanks.

Comment: @SivaKondapiVenkata You can return the accumulator in the same line using the comma operator

Comment: @SivaKondapiVenkata Good job :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another take on using `reduce` to group by the values.

It reduces to an object, which is then transformed to an array of arrays.

```js
let valueArray = ["100", "330", "22", "100", "4.7", "0.01", "0.01", "330", "0.01", "100", "47", "22", "100", "0.01"];

let groupedByValue = Object.values(valueArray
  .reduce((acc, x)=>{
      let arr = acc[x] || [];
      arr.push(x);
      acc[x] = arr;
      return acc;
   },{}));
 
console.log(groupedByValue);
```

***Extra***

Here's a version that will group the unique values by the same format.
It was something cooked up when this question was originally completely misunderstood by yours truly.  (it happens...)

```js
let valueArray = ["100", "330", "22", "102", "4.7", "0.01", "0.02", "330", "0.01", "101", "47", "23", "100", "0.02"];

let groupedByFormat = Object.values(valueArray
  .reduce((acc, x)=>{
      let val = x.trim();
      let format = val.replace(/\d/g,'0');
      let arr = acc[format] || [];
      if(!arr.includes(val)) {
     arr.push(val);
     acc[format] = arr.sort();
    }
    return acc;
   },{}));
 
console.log(groupedByFormat);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of what you want using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/el/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
const data = ["100", "330", "22", "100", "4.7", "0.01", "0.01", "330", "0.01", "100", "47", "22", "100", "0.01"];

const unique = new Set(data);
for(let num of unique) {
  console.log(data.filter(d => d == num));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Also it can be done like this:

```js
const {log} = console;
const arr = ["100", "330", "22", "100", "4.7", "0.01", "0.01", "330", "0.01", "100", "47", "22", "100", "0.01"];
log([...new Set(arr)].map( x => arr.filter( y => y === x )));
```